# Replace a specific line with formatted output in text file

Tags: bash, sed

I have a program that outputs data to a textfile, but as of now it just concatenates on the end of the file.  I want to take some formatted output using printf and tell sed or awk to replace a certain line in that .txt.

I've tried using several different methods.  Right now I'm trying to fine lines that start with $name and replace it with

```
printf "%-12s%-9s%-9s%-12s%-9s%-14s%-10s\n" "$name" "$quiz" "$hw" "$midterm" "$final"          
                  "$numberGrade" "$letterGrade"
```

i'm trying to use sed -i /^$name/\c ...    But I can't find a way to preserve the printf formatting if I set it to a variable.  Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: can you provide sample data to work with ?

Comment: The variables in the printf function (name, quiz, hw, midterm, final, numberGrade, letterGrade) must be output in the exact format as the printf in the code block specifies.  The pattern to match would be the first line with a matching $name variable.  Output would look somethin like: Jon  89  90  45  32  72.2  C-   (except output would be formatted like in printf.  So, if a line matched the word "Jon", that line would be replaced with new data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should give us an example of input stream and an example of expected output.

Now, some elements of research :

- awk provide an implementation of printf function
- You could try something like :

  ```
  formatRow=$(printf "%-12s%-9s%-9s%-12s%-9s%-14s%-10s" "$name" "$quiz" "$hw" "$midterm" "$final" "$numberGrade" "$letterGrade")
  sed -i "s/^$name.*/$formatRow/" filename
  ```

Comment: I've added the missing `s` for your `sed` expression.

Comment: Ok, thank you.  I had tried several sed commands, and for some reason could not get a variable to hold format, but this works.  However, it does not replace the entire line, it only replaces the pattern matched with the printf....hrmm

Comment: @user2079828 : Ya, try this one instead of my previous sed :
sed -i "s/^$name.*/$formatRow/"

Comment: @IdrissNeumann Instead of suggesting modifications in comments, you should update your answer.

Comment: I hope there are not slashes in the fields... otherwise it will explode in your face (or bite you in the back, or ...)

Comment: @devnull : Thank you and sorry, I'm not yet familiar with the habits and features of the site, but it will come :)

Comment: Yes, I've been up too long, should have thought of just adding in the regex.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf : Thanks for this information. I did not know the `-v` option, and then as I usually use sub-shells (which is not a bad practice when you have no option to catch the output of a command)